# Attach each EIP to each Nat Gatway in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-nat-gateway

I'm creating two public subnets that will each contain a nat gateay. My code, attempts to create these nats per subnet, and then allocate the eip to each. However, since my for each starts the code block, it looks like the allocation id became us-east-* instead of the id of the eip.

Variables.tf:

```
    variable "public_subnet_numbers" {
  type = map(number)
 
  description = "Map of AZ to a number that should be used for public subnets"
 
  default = {
    "us-east-1a" = 1
    "us-east-1b" = 2
    #"us-east-1c" = 3
  }
}
 
variable "private_subnet_numbers" {
  type = map(number)
 
  description = "Map of AZ to a number that should be used for private subnets"
 
  default = {
    "us-east-1a" = 4
    "us-east-1b" = 5
    #"us-east-1c" = 6
  }
}
 
variable "vpc_cidr" {
  type        = string
  description = "The IP range to use for the VPC"
  default     = "192.168.0.0/16"
}
```

Main.tf:

```
    resource "aws_eip" "nat" {
  count = 2
  vpc = true
 
  lifecycle {
    # prevent_destroy = true
  }
 
  tags = {
    Name        = "cf-${var.infra_env}-eip"
    Project     = "cf.io"
    Environment = var.infra_env
    VPC         = aws_vpc.vpc.id
    ManagedBy   = "terraform"
    Role        = "private"
  }
}
 

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "ngw" {
  for_each = var.private_subnet_numbers
  subnet_id = each.value.id #aws_subnet.public[each.key].id
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat[each.key].id
 
 
  tags = {
    Name        = "cf-${var.infra_env}-ngw"
    Project     = "cf.io"
    VPC         = aws_vpc.vpc.id
    Environment = var.infra_env
    ManagedBy   = "terraform"
    Role        = "private"
  }
}
```

Error:

```
    Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on ../terraform/modules/networking/gateways.tf line 42, in resource "aws_nat_gateway" "ngw":
│   42:   allocation_id = aws_eip.nat[each.key].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_eip.nat is tuple with 2 elements
│     │ each.key is "us-east-1a"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: a number is required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on ../terraform/modules/networking/gateways.tf line 42, in resource "aws_nat_gateway" "ngw":
│   42:   allocation_id = aws_eip.nat[each.key].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_eip.nat is tuple with 2 elements
│     │ each.key is "us-east-1b"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: a number is required.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mark B mentioned mixing the `count` and `for_each` is not recommended. In your current setup using exclusively `for_each` is the way to go based on the `private_subnet_numbers` variable.

In your `aws_eip.nat` resource change `count` to `for_each`

```
resource "aws_eip" "nat" {
  for_each = var.private_subnet_numbers
  vpc = true
}
```

Next in your resource `aws_nat_gateway.ngw` you should refer to `subnet ids` using `each`

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "ngw" {
  for_each      = var.private_subnet_numbers
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.public[each.key].id
  ....
}
```

And the code as a whole for clarity

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
 ... vpc configurations ...
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  for_each = var.private_subnet_numbers
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.vpc.id
 ... subnet configurations ...
}

resource "aws_eip" "nat" {
  for_each = var.private_subnet_numbers
  vpc      = true

  lifecycle {
    # prevent_destroy = true
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "cf-${var.infra_env}-eip"
    Project     = "cf.io"
    Environment = var.infra_env
    VPC         = aws_vpc.vpc.id
    ManagedBy   = "terraform"
    Role        = "private"
  }
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "ngw" {
  for_each      = var.private_subnet_numbers
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.public[each.key].id
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat[each.key].id


  tags = {
    Name        = "cf-${var.infra_env}-ngw"
    Project     = "cf.io"
    VPC         = aws_vpc.vpc.id
    Environment = var.infra_env
    ManagedBy   = "terraform"
    Role        = "private"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing `count` and `for_each`. The easiest way to solve this would be to use `for_each` in your EIP creation as well, which makes sense because you are creating an EIP for each NAT. That would also make your code work better if you decided to add another subnet later, you wouldn't need to go in and change the `count` from `2` to `3`.

Otherwise, you need to use the [index function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/index_function) to convert the `each` value to an index number.